# How to pass VT-BSTR object reference to PIC X in Cobol

Tags: cobol

In Micro Focus Native Cobol I have this variable:

```
01 aCharArray object reference.
```

It's **VT-BSTR**. How to move its value to standard Cobol PIC X(n) variable?

Answer (score 0):

I would presume its an instance of a CharacterArray so you can use getValue or getValuewithSize if you want to specify a size.

If you look at the base class library docs in the Net Express help you should find details on these methods.